# How does one acquire Basic Auth credentials from JavaScript/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, get, basic-authentication

My webpage needs to pass on credentials delivered in a Basic Authentication header to a REST call (a GET in this case) which itself requires Basic Authentication. 
Essentially I just want to pass on the same basic auth header, since both the server and the target of the REST request use the same db to verify the username/password combo.

However, despite extensive googling, I just can't find a way to do that without bringing in some extra stuff like node.

I'd like to stick to pure JavaScript and HTML.

Comment: so, you can't set a header in the REST request? somewhere near line 37

Comment: @Jaromanda-x But what do I put in the header? I need to get the username/password combination somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use client side JS to read the credentials used to load the currently viewed page.

Comment: How would one get around this, then?